# Why is my Webserver not accessible outside LAN?

Tags: port-forwarding

so i tried to set up my first web server using a raspberry pie. It all works great in my local network, from every machine and using both 192.168.178.59, which is my Pi's local ip and using the global ip. I forwarded Port 80, 443 and a bunch of others for some side projects.

The Problem is, that you can't connect to the website with either ip (obviously not the local one) from outside the local network. I checked that the ports are open using [this](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) port checker and all forwarded ports seem to be open.

For good measure, i changed the server port to 8181, which i also forwarded. I can still connect via LAN and it shows the port in the url, so i'm sure it worked, but connection from outside the LAN is still not possible. I also made sure that other services can use that port from outside the LAN, by hosting a chess server on the Pi, which worked as inteded.

So why could it be, that the webserver acts up like that? Could it be some sort of firewall problem? How would i go and check that? I tried lot's of things already, but none seemed to work.

One last thing to note could be that connecting via global ip automatically changes the ip displayed in the url to 192.168.178.59:8181, so the local ip. It's a wordpress server and that is also the url defined in wordpress. Could that automatically change the ip to the local one when trying to connect from outside?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"ip automatically changes the ip displayed in the url to 192.168.178.59:8181"* -> That's no good.  You should try hosting just a plain, static html page with minimal or no content to see if it changes that way too.  If not it is a wordpress problem.

Comment: What webserver do you use (like Apache or Nginx)?

Comment: @goldilocks You were right, changing the site url in wordpress form my local to the open ip worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jjj I use Apache2, i was able to fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that wordpress automatically assigned my local ip to the site, which meant that devices outside of my network automatically looked for the local one, which they don't have access to. Changing the ip in wordpress (settings, general) did the trick. goldilocks also adviced me into that direction, even though i found the fix by luck, without the troubleshooting.